# Google Places Autocomplete in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to use this project https://github.com/AdamBCo/GooglePlacesAutocomplete
but when I downloaded it and put my key "Key for browser apps" it gives me this error (when I start to type in the search field).

```
2015-05-24 01:37:36.154 GooglePlacesAutocomplete[6780:185340] Length: 1
2015-05-24 01:37:36.806 GooglePlacesAutocomplete[6780:185340] Search: 0
2015-05-24 01:37:36.806 GooglePlacesAutocomplete[6780:185340] AutoComplete URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=I&types=establishment|geocode&location=0,0&radius=500&language=en&key=???   (removed my key here)
2015-05-24 01:37:37.100 GooglePlacesAutocomplete[6780:185340] -[__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102f7d410
2015-05-24 01:37:37.112 GooglePlacesAutocomplete[6780:185340] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102f7d410'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104715a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104f97bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010471cd1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001046749dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104674578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   GooglePlacesAutocomplete            0x0000000102f78824 -[SearchViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 308
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103384e03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103364901 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010337a78c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001033071c3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000103118c58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010310d87e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010310d6ee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010307b36e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010307c482 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010307caed _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010464a507 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010464a460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104640293 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010463fbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106dc0a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010328d580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  GooglePlacesAutocomplete            0x0000000102f75153 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001068ef145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm using Xcode 6 and iPhone 6 simulator. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For my last project, I wrote a library to Achieve something that you are trying. It is Drop-in control to Add Autocompletion Google place search feature in iOS Application.

In just 3 Steps you will be able to integrate it. Here it is:
https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField

Comment: Autocomplete error The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support).

Comment: i m als getting the same error as @NileshParmar ,@Mrug

Comment: but what the solution bro @Mrug. if you know anything about it please let me know. thanks.